# Showing maps route in android bigPicturestyle notification

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, notifications, google-now

I'm making an app that will send reminder notifications about certain events at varying locations. I'd like to use BigPictureStyle to show a route from source to the event location in the notification itself, very similar to, if not the same as, the [Google Now reminder.](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4wXpelEvBKaZlpFNXpWNnhRaUU/edit)
This is an Android app for API >= 14.

I've been looking all over the place to discover how to get this to work. Any help or redirection is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For generating static images via Google Maps, you can use the [Static Maps API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) to request an image. In your case, you would want to use [Static Map Paths](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Paths) to draw the route between the start and end locations, potentially using something like the [Google Maps DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#DirectionsService) to get the individual directions you need.

Comment: This might get me part way there, thank you. It turns out that there is actually a Google SnapShotReadyCallback library which is exactly what I'm asking for in terms of the picture.